# How do you redeploy javascript in Idea when using a Tomcat configuration

Tags: java, javascript, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm working on a java/javascript webapp that runs on tomcat.

We're working with IDEA and I've managed to get debugging set up for both the client and server code at the same time, which is great.  I did have hot redeployment of the javascript set up when running Tomcat manually, however I find when running Tomcat through IDEA this doesnt work as it's setting stuff up somewhere in my users folder.

I was going to just set up a deployment configuration to go to that folder but I can't see any of the javascript files in there.

Is it possible to get the best of both worlds and have debugging and automatic deployment working together?

**Update**

Here's my config:

I'm using maven to build a specific profile rather than using 'build war exploded'.  I suspect the latter wont work to build as quite a lot of custom properties need supplying by maven at compile time.

I also now have war exploded set in start up in deployment.

[image]

Comment: only javascript application or spring etc. ?

Comment: @user3145373 spring etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I was having problems because I had `antiResourceLocking=true` in my tomcat context.xml config file.

I had switched this on as I was having problems with things hanging onto the war files and stopping recompilation.

changing to use `antiJARLocking="true"` instead seems to have solved both problems.  Redeployment is now working in idea and I'm not experiencing problems with things holding files open

Answer (score 3):

In `Run - >Edit Configurations -> select tomcat instance`.

then on `update action : restart` option

and in `deployment` tab instead of `war` use `war exploded`.

Now click on green button for run project it will ask option then select update resources and ok then refresh your page it will show change.

Keep one thing in mind that clear the cache.

Here is a screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Still face problem post me.

Comment: thanks very much.  Just trying it now.  What does 'On frame deactivation' mean?

Comment: You will get about it on http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/deployment-console.html

Comment: hmm.  Its not working for me.  It does appear to be trying to do something but it's not updating.  I wonder if it's to do with the fact I'm using maven - I'll post my config

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596779/intellij-and-tomcat-changed-files-are-not-automatically-recognized-by-tomcat

Comment: that seems to just outline the same steps.  Not sure what it's not working - I might drop jetbrains an email and then post if I get a fix

Comment: Okay that also fine, otherwise you can post me tomorrow, tomorrow I can give you time to solve it. Today I have some work to complete.