# Server is not connected when trying to deploy with intellij

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, war, auto-update

I am trying to build, deploy and debug my webapp inside intellij.

I have setup my tomcat using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19609115/162345) answer and I was able to get the server running. The issue is that my webapp is not being deployed, though it is defined in the `deployment` tab.

I am getting the following error:
**server is not connected. Deploy is not available**

If I copy the war and start the server everything works Ok. With ports 8080 and 8000.

What am I doing wrong?

Just in case it is somehow related, the project is build with Maven & Spring

I added the Run/Debug Configuration for the Server:

**Server Tab**
[image: Server Tab]

**Deployment Tab**
[image: Deployment tab]

Debug Console output:

```
D:\development\infra\appServers\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\bin\catalina.bat run
[2014-08-05 01:23:11,413] Artifact devstage:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\chaim\.IntelliJIdea13\system\tomcat\Unnamed_devstage_4"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "D:\development\infra\appServers\apache-tomcat-7.0.47"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "D:\development\infra\appServers\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45"
Using CLASSPATH:       "D:\development\infra\appServers\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\bin\bootstrap.jar;D:\development\infra\appServers\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Aug 05, 2014 1:23:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.29 using APR version 1.4.8.
Aug 05, 2014 1:23:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Aug 05, 2014 1:23:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013)
Aug 05, 2014 1:23:12 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Aug 05, 2014 1:23:12 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Aug 05, 2014 1:23:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 902 ms
Aug 05, 2014 1:23:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 05, 2014 1:23:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Aug 05, 2014 1:23:12 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Aug 05, 2014 1:23:12 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Aug 05, 2014 1:23:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 35 ms
[2014-08-05 01:23:21,363] Artifact devstage:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Aug 05, 2014 1:23:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\development\infra\appServers\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\webapps\manager
[2014-08-05 01:23:38,311] Artifact devstage:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
```

Comment: have a look at possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163910/tomcat-in-idea-war-exploded-server-is-not-connected-deploy-is-not-available

Comment: That's not a duplicate...

Answer (score 3):

### In short:

After setting my IntelliJ configuration to run the latest version of Tomcat that I was running in the background my problem was resolved.

### A brief description:

I had the exact same error in my IntelliJ 14 while I had a setup and was working on another machine. 
While the source of the issue can differ, in my case here was the root cause:

I basically had two different versions of Tomcat Installed on my machine. Tomcat 8 was running in the background on port 8090 and despite of setting my debugger instance port to be 8091 it was giving me the following error:

> Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.

and The following warnings:

> 1:21:18 PM It is possible to bind and connect to localhost:8091 at the same time - application server will probably compete with some other software on the port
>
> 1:32:39 PM Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason:
>              Unable to ping server at localhost:1099

After setting my IntelliJ configuration to run the latest version of Tomcat that I was running in the background my problem was resolved.

> Hint: Running applications in debug mode can slow them down a fair bit. I usually have two instances running. One in debug mode and one in normal mode in two different ports. This way I can have a normal instance of my web application as well as a debugger instance for more in depth investigations.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, this problem was due to a JAVA_OPTS variable defined in catalina.bat (or catalina.sh).

I only commented the first line of catalina.bat and everything started working.
Here is the line :

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

To comment, put `rem` in front of it. `rem` is the way to comment a line in windows .bat files.

I suppose that this line conflicts with IntelliJ JAVA_OPTS settings. In fact, IntelliJ tries to set a port on tomcat to use as a debugger, but the catalina.bat JAVA_OPTS variable deleted this setting.

Comment: I had the same problem with a piece of legacy software. In my case, the JAVA_OPTS were overwritten in setenv.sh. This is the default location for user defined env vars. Saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

(3.2) Set JRE_HOME or JAVA_HOME (required)

These variables are used to specify location of a Java Runtime Environment or of a Java Development Kit that is used to start Tomcat.

The JRE_HOME variable is used to specify location of a JRE. The JAVA_HOME variable is used to specify location of a JDK.

Using JAVA_HOME provides access to certain additional startup options that are not allowed when JRE_HOME is used.

If both JRE_HOME and JAVA_HOME are specified, JRE_HOME is used.

Answer (score 0):

I meet this problem when try to import a project from eclipse to IDEA.

My solution is, delete the `.idea` folder, re-import the whole project. I don't know what's the accurate cause of this problem, but is works for me.

Now the log looks like that:

```
/Library/Tomcat/bin/catalina.sh run

[2015-09-22 12:40:57,906] Artifact bookstore:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
XXXXXX
Connected to server
[2015-09-22 12:40:58,848] Artifact bookstore:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
XXXXXX
[2015-09-22 12:41:07,862] Artifact bookstore:war exploded: Artifact is deployed successfully
[2015-09-22 12:41:07,863] Artifact bookstore:war exploded: Deploy took 9,015 milliseconds
```

Comment: Your log still shows you have a problem: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible reason could be that **you manually run a standalone Wildfly** apps server and copy your packages manually in its `deployment` folder.

In this case Intellij tries to run Wildfly (even if you have stopped your manually run Wildfly) and to copy app's package for deployment. But there is already such a package in `deployment folder`.

Remove `myapp.ear` or `myapp.war` from `.../wildfly/standalone/deployments/` and Run or Debug from Intellij.