# In IntelliJ, can Live Edit be used with Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I'm testing IntelliJ Idea for web development.  I'm trying to get live edit to work with updates to html files.  My whole project is JavaEE deployed on Tomcat 8.0.12.  Currently there is nothing but one index.html file in my web directory as I'm trying to test live edit.

I have the plugin installed and enabled in IntelliJ as well as Chrome and Chromium (using LinuxMint 17 KDE).  I've been at this for a couple hours now and must be missing something.  I can't get it to work in 13.1.4 or the EAP(Early Access Program) 14.  When I "reload in browser" from IntelliJ, I see the action happen in the browser, but the actual content does not update.

I've tried debugging the normal exploded war deploy and creating a javascript debugger deploy.

Am I completely wrong and this won't work with JavaEE or Tomcat deploy?
Should there be a difference between Chromium and Chrome?

Comment: Have you seen this Answer?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596779/intellij-and-tomcat-changed-files-are-not-automatically-recognized-by-tomcat/19609115#19609115

Answer (score 4):

I tested it on Windows 8.1 x64 with Tomcat 8.0.12, IntelliJ 13.1 with LiveEdit version 1.19 and Chrome version 37 using the [JetBrains browser plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jetbrains-ide-support/hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji). It seemed to work, however all I did was follow the [JetBrains guide](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/live-editing-of-html-css-and-javascript.html#d197173e347). You just have to make sure that in your server conf you have set Chrome as the browser, and ticked "with JavaScript debugger". The LiveEdit does not come prepackaged with IntelliJ, you have to download it separately from Default Settings->Plugins. Most importantly, it works (or at least it's written that it works) only with Debug run.

There shouldn't be much of a difference between Chrome and Chromium, since on Kubuntu 14.04 I've used Chromium with JetBrains' PyCharm and the same browser plugin.

I hope I was of help,
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That is exactly what I did, just on LinuxMint.  Oddly enough, I have it working on PCBSD 10.0.3 with IntelliJ 14. My LinuxMint version will still not work (13.1 or 14).

Comment: This solved the same issue for me; I just had to check "with JavaScript debugger".