# Tomcat (embeded), make changes without restart

Tags: java, tomcat, refresh

How to refresh static files, like html/css in TomCat (embeded)? Without restarting server. InelliJ Idea. By using some kind of config

```
public class TomStart {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws LifecycleException,
            InterruptedException, ServletException {

        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        tomcat.setPort(8082);
        tomcat.addContext("/", "/web");
        Context ctx = tomcat.addContext("/", new File(".").getAbsolutePath());

        Tomcat.addServlet(ctx, "Embedded", new HttpServlet() {
            @Override
            protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {

                Writer w = resp.getWriter();
                w.write("Embedded Tomcat servlet.\n");
                w.flush();
                w.close();
            }
        });

        ctx.addServletMappingDecoded("/*", "Embedded");

        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ and Tomcat....changed files are not automatically recognized by Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596779/intellij-and-tomcat-changed-files-are-not-automatically-recognized-by-tomcat)

Answer (score 0):

[I found answer in debug settings, now page text updates with refreshing of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/annc7.png)

[**REF to image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/annc7.png)